# track my website visitors with .htaccess resrictions

Tags: php, html, database, .htaccess, ip

I have a website that only few IP's have access to see (list of ip's in the .htaccess file)
now i want to create some log to track the ip's that tried to get into my website and they are not allowed - not on the list. if it is possible to write every attempt to the database? 
and if it's not possible to know the IP , maybe just write the date and time they try to.
any suggestion? 
thanks,
Mor

Comment: If you want to stop them at Apache, then you can still view accesses with the forbidden/accessdenied response codes in the `access_log`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have console access and pretty much the default configurations, just issue

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access_log | awk '{if ($9 == 403) print $1}'
```

in the cli.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2014:18:45:21 +0100] "GET /forbidden/test.jpg HTTP/1.1" 403
```

The first column is the IP, and the 9th (403) is the HTTP status. Each "column" is delimited by space.

Comment: Hi @motanelu can i get to access_log from direct admin or FTP ?